# NFC Tags isn't detected although scanning view is shown

Tags: swift, swiftui, nfc, core-nfc

I’m trying to read NFC Tags in iOS App using CoreNFC.
Scanning view is successfully shown but it doesn’t recognize any cards.
Target iOS setting is 16.0 and Xcode version is 15.0

I’ve checked that `readerSessionDidBecomeActive` func was called, and set up following things:

- add `Privacy - NFC Scan Usage Description` to info.plist
- add `ISO18092 system codes for NFC Tag Reader Session` to info.plist and add an item valued 0003 (I wanted to test for IC cards)
- add `Near Field Communication Tag Reading` to Capabilities
- add `NFC Tag Reading` to enabled capabilities of Provisioning Profile
- confirm the position of my iPhone and NFC tag by using another app
- add `Tag-Specific Data Protocol(TAG)` to entitlements file
- Clean and Rebuild

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.